# having trouble passing Facebook review process

Tags: facebook, submission

I have an application (window exe) that gathers information from our clients and posts images to Facebook. It use a Facebook app to help with its posting, but also uses an executable and a server with php scripts to accomplish its tasks. 
The problem is that when i try to get the Facebook app approved, Facebook fails the app since it does not seem to be using the permissions i am requesting. This is probably due to the fact that the permissions are used in the php scripts, rather than directly by the Facebook app (which is not runnable outside of the infrastructure i have described above).
So i do not know how to get this app certified and worry they will turn it off after April 30th. Has anyone else had troubles like this and if so, how did they resolve the issues?

Comment: The general recommendation for stuff that the review team will not be able to test themselves, is to record a screencast/video showing how the app works and what using it results in, and giving a link to that together with your review instructions. (If you could make it available for them to test withing your infrastructure, like by providing them with a test user account or something, that would be better though.)

Comment: CBroe - that is an interesting idea, i will give it a try and see if it yields results. I am hoping that they actually read the submissions, the turn around was so fast (~12 hours) and ignored so much i am wondering if my app is being evaluated by a man or a automatic process.